# Trazer valor de um registro agrupado

Tags: sql, oracle

Prezados colegas agarrei em uma query que pensei ser simples mas está complicado!

Eu tenho uma base de dados onde tenho todas as minhas NF por por produto de entrada de mercadoria, preciso achar o valor do produto na ultima entrada do ano.

Eu cheguei fácil na data da nota de cada produto, agrupei por produto e dei um `max` na data, até ai tudo bem, mas pra trazer o valor que ta sendo o problema, se eu acrescentar o valor no `group by` ele mostra o produtos varias vezes!

```
SELECT produto, MAX(data) 
 FROM notas 
 WHERE data < '2016-01-01' 
 GROUP BY produto <--- precisava trazer o valor da ultima entrada nessa query
```

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: tenta colocar o `trunc` na data: Where trunc(data) < to_date('2016-01-01', 'yyyy-dd-mm')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois te muito matutar, essa foi a query que eu consegui chegar, espero que ajude a você:

```
SELECT p.produto, p.data, n.valor
FROM notas n
INNER JOIN (SELECT produto, MAX(data) as data
            FROM notas
            WHERE data < '2016-01-01' 
            GROUP BY produto
) p ON (p.produto = n.produto and p.data = n.data)
ORDER BY p.data DESC;
```

Se alguem souber de uma query melhor, por favor nos ajude a melhorar ;)

Comment: A ideia e essa mesmo, mas o banco e Oracle acho que não tem LIMIT.

Comment: Hummmm.. vou tentar algo parecido aqui e te mando se conseguir ;)

Comment: E também ele não aceitaria eu ter o valor nas colunas e não ter no group by. 
A tabela tem milhões de campos eu estou simplificando para ficar fácil o entendimento. mas ela guarda os itens da nota, a chave seria  NumNota, produto, e data, no caso eu precisaria do valor do produto na ultima nota do ano.

Comment: @DavidD.Rocha eu preciso esclarecer antes de continuar. Acredito que talvez o group by não seja a melhor solução para o que você precisa. O você quer é dado um determinado produto, saber quando foi a última compra dele e o último valor? Ou para todos os produtos, saber qual foi a última data de compra e o último valor dele? E em relação ao valor, é o valor do produto ou da nota fiscal?

Comment: Para todos os produtos o ultimo valor.
Eu não tenho valor de nota nessa tabela ela e aberta por produtos.
Ex:
*Nota   |     produto |   valor    
123             1581         2.85
123             1582         3.30
123             1583         4.50*

e ai os produtos vão se repetindo em notas diferente com valores e datas diferentes, ai eu precisava saber o valor do produto na ultima nota que entrou em 2015.

vlws

Comment: Meu exemplo de tabela não deu certo! rs

Comment: E isso mesmo @Rubico deu certinho!  Muito obrigado, eu não sabia que podia  fazer join com um select =) vlw pelo aprendizado!